# private field with public accessor on c++

Tags: c++

Sorry for probably too simple question, i'm newbie in c++. How should I implement `int` field which can be modified only inside class but have public accessor?

In c# we can write this simple code:

```
public int MsgSeqNum { get; private set; }
```

On c++ I should likely write something like that (pseudo-code):

```
public:
    int GetMsgSeqNum() { return msgSeqNum; };
private:
    int msgSeqNum;
```

Is it the right way to do things? Will `GetMsgSeqNum` be inlined? Should i manually mark method as `inline`? Do I introduce latency adding this method call?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  Have some faith in your compiler, but feel free to make it `inline int GetMsgSeqNum` if you want to.

Comment: If it's read-only to clients then, as you have done, don't provide a setter. If it has complex logic or needs guards to check input (which your example doesn't as it's an int) then provide a private set method too and use it internally.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin there is no need use inine here, 7.1.2 Function specifiers `A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.` C++11 standard, and it was same way before.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it the right way to do things?

Yes it is thru you should mark function returning argument as `const`

```
int GetMsgSeqNum()const { return msgSeqNum; };
```

As meintioned in comments, `const` will not allow you to modify object, thus if you need to do so, you should either make getter non const, or declare members you are going to change in your stil `const` getter as `mutable`.

> Will GetMsgSeqNum be inlined?

Most likely yes, any function that is defined inside class declaration has implicit inline. Thru inline no matter explicit or implicit doesn't guarantee that function will be inlined.

> Do I introduce latency adding this method call?

Most likely no, any sane compiler implementation will optimize such call.

Comment: Just because a function returns a value does not mean it should be made const. A function can modify the internal state of the object and still return a value.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think it's just badly worded, he probably meant that because it is an accessor (as opposed to a mutator), it should be const. It could definitely do with a rephrasing because it is ambiguous - could be interpreted as meaning "returning argument as const" as in the return value is const.

Comment: @JBentley Was thinking the same thing. Figured I'd give it a few before I dropped an edit into it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious As far as I can see from example given, there is no intention to do anything apart from returning value of private field. But in general yes there can be situations when getter should be non const. Thru I'd consider using mutable in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only **sane** way to do this in `C++`... You can try

```
public:
    inline int GetMsgSeqNum() const { return msgSeqNum; } //const -> doesn't change object
```

But you cannot force the compiler to stick to `inline`. The compiler decides whether to `inline` this method or not. There is no serious loss of performance if the compiler does not inline the method, so don't worry.

In MSVC there is `__forceinline`-keyword where you can force the compiler to inline your method, but as with getters and setters this might be a little over the edge.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) on this.